# Why is this C++ expression involving overloaded operators and implicit conversions ambiguous?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, operators, ambiguous

`operator bool` breaks the use of `operator<` in the following example. Can anyone explain why `bool` is just as relevant in the `if (a < 0)` expression as the specific operator, an whether there is a workaround?

```
struct Foo {
    Foo() {}
    Foo(int x) {}

    operator bool() const { return false; }

    friend bool operator<(const Foo& a, const Foo& b) {
        return true;
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo a, b;
    if (a < 0) {
        a = 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

When I compile, I get:

```
g++ foo.cpp
foo.cpp: In function 'int main()':
foo.cpp:18:11: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator<' (operand types are 'Foo' and 'int')
     if (a < 0) {
           ^
foo.cpp:18:11: note: candidate: operator<(int, int) <built-in>
foo.cpp:8:17: note: candidate: bool operator<(const Foo&, const Foo&)
     friend bool operator<(const Foo& a, const Foo& b)
```

Comment: `0` is of type `int`, not of type `Foo`

Comment: Do you really need both those implicit conversions? Single implicit conversions can cause headaches, but two way implicit conversions are a sure fire migraine.

Comment: Make the single argument constructor `explicit`

Comment: BTW: You haven't defined a assignment operator for `a = 0;` this will probably lead to another error message...

Comment: This is a cut down example for the question.

Comment: @user1810087 That uses the converting constructor.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The important points are:

First, there are two relevant overloads of `operator <`.

- `operator <(const Foo&, const Foo&)`. Using this overload requires a user-defined conversion of the literal `0` to `Foo` using `Foo(int)`.
- `operator <(int, int)`. Using this overload requires converting `Foo` to `bool` with the user-defined `operator bool()`, followed by a *promotion* to `int` (this is, in standardese, different from a conversion, as has been pointed out by Bo Persson).

The question here is: From whence does the ambiguity arise? Certainly, the first call, which requires only a user-defined conversion, is more sensible than the second, which requires a user-defined conversion followed by a promotion?

But that is not the case. The standard assigns a rank to each *candidate*. However, there is no rank for "user-defined conversion followed by a promotion". This has the same rank as only using a user-defined conversion. Simply (but informally) put, the ranking sequence looks a bit like this:

1. exact match
2. (only) promotion required
3. (only) implicit conversion required (including "unsafe" ones inherited from C such as `float` to `int`)
4. user-defined conversion required

(Disclaimer: As mentioned, this is informal. It gets significantly more complex when multiple arguments are involved, and I also didn't mention references or cv-qualification. This is just intended as a rough overview.)

So this, hopefully, explains why the call is ambiguous. Now for the practical part of how to fix this. *Almost never* does someone who provides `operator bool()` want it to be implicitly used in expressions involving integer arithmetic or comparisons. In C++98, there were obscure workarounds, ranging from `std::basic_ios<CharT, Traits>::operator void *` to "improved" safer versions involving pointers to members or incomplete private types. Fortunately, C++11 introduced a more readable and consistent way of preventing integer promotion after implicit uses of `operator bool()`, which is to mark the operator as `explicit`. This will remove the `operator <(int, int)` overload entirely, rather than just "demoting" it.

As others have mentioned, you can also mark the `Foo(int)` constructor as explicit. This will have the converse effect of removing the `operator <(const Foo&, const Foo&)` overload.

A third solution would be to provide additional overloads, e.g.:

- `operator <(int, const Foo&)`
- `operator <(const Foo&, int)`

The latter, in this example, will then be preferred over the above-mentioned overloads as an exact match, even if you did not introduce `explicit`. The same goes e.g. for

- `operator <(const Foo&, long long)`

which would be preferred over `operator <(const Foo&, const Foo&)` in `a < 0` because its use requires only a promotion.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer. I am marking this as the correct one. Yes, my questing was with regard to the ranking of the match, as it seemed bool->int was an _additional_ conversion. But it is explained in terms of _promotion_. Additionally, the fix to to have `explicit operator bool` indeed, you would almost never want further promotion. Thanks to others too for their input.

Answer (score 25):

The problem here is that C++ has two options to deal with `a < 0` expression:

- Convert `a` to `bool`, and compare the result to `0` with built-in operator `<` (one conversion)
- Convert `0` to `Foo`, and compare the results with `<` that you defined (one conversion)

Both approaches are equivalent to the compiler, so it issues an error.

You can make this explicit by removing the conversion in the second case:

```
if (a < Foo(0)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: convert `a` to `bool`, yes but `bool` is not the same as `int`,

Comment: @jkjyuio Zero is not only an `int`, C++ treats it as any type to which it could be converted, including `int`, `bool`, pointers, floats, doubles, and so on. When zero is treated as `bool`, it's the same as `false`. It does not count as a conversion.

Comment: More precisely, the conversion from `bool` to `int` is an *integral promotion* rather than a *conversion*.  See section 13.3.3.2 [over.ics.rank] in (for example) [n4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf).  Yes, it is horribly complicated.  Avoid implicit conversions!

Answer (score 4):

Because compiler can not choose between `bool operator <(const Foo &,const Foo &)` and `operator<(bool, int)` which both fits in this situation.

In order to fix the issue make second constructor `explicit`:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo() {}
    explicit Foo(int x) {}

    operator bool() const { return false; }

    friend bool operator<(const Foo& a, const Foo& b)
    {
        return true;
    }
};
```

**Edit:**
Ok, at last I got a real point of the question :) OP asks why his compiler offers `operator<(int, int)` as a candidate, though ***"multi-step conversions are not allowed"***.

**Answer:**
Yes, in order to call `operator<(int, int)` object `a` needs to be converted `Foo -> bool -> int`. **But**, C++ Standard does not actually say that "multi-step conversions are illegal".

**§ 12.3.4  [class.conv]**

> At most one user-defined conversion (constructor or conversion
>   function) is implicitly applied to a single value.

`bool` to `int` **is not user-defined** conversion, hence it is legal and compiler has the full right to chose `operator<(int, int)` as a candidate.

Comment: no because the compiler did not list operator<(bool,int). only (Foo, Foo) and (int, int).

Comment: In your case indeed, `operator<(int, int)`. However, MSVC 2017 does lists `operator<(bool,int)`.

Comment: Does this mean converting `bool` to `int` does not count as a conversion step.so they are the _same_ type?

Comment: I am not sure about a conversion step, but `int` and `bool` are definitely different types in Standard C++ (although, in C and probably pre-Standard C++ there were no `bool`, only `int`)

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what the compiler tells you.

One approach for solving the `if (a < 0)` for the compiler is to use the `Foo(int x)` constructor you've provided to create object from 0.

The second one is to use the `operator bool` conversion and compare it against the `int` (promotion). You can read more about it in [Numeric promotions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) section.

Hence, it is ambiguous for the compiler and it cannot decide which way you want it to go.

Comment: Why is comparing `bool` vs `int` not counted as an _additional_ conversion?

Comment: @jkj - `bool` to `int` is a "promotion" and not a conversion. :-) Note that the chapter "Standard conversions" takes 7 pages to explain in the standard document. A full explanation doesn't fit on StackOverflow. Your basic problem is that your class offers implicit conversions both to and from the class. Most people avoid doing that for the precise reason you have noticed - it gets confusing both for the readers and for the compiler.

Comment: @Bo Persson, thanks for pointing this out. Arne Vogel has explained it in detail above.